# Socket.io Client.emit not working inside if loop

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am starting with Node.js. I want to emit some data to client at the starting of every hour.

```
var d = new Date();
var a=d.getDate();
var h = d.getHours();
if(h<10){
    h="0"+h;
}
if(d<10){
    d="0"+d;
}
time=a+""+h;

//Message from redis
rClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    var vals=message.split("#");

    if(vals[1]!=time){
        var msg="sending reset";
        console.log(msg);
        client.emit('hreset',msg);
        time=vals[1];
    }
}
```

inside client

```
socket.on('hreset', function(val) {
    alert(val);
    reset();
    alert("reseting Data completed");
});
```

But it's not triggering the code in client. If I change the condition from `!=` to `==` it's working fine and triggering every second. But not working in case of `!=`. It's going inside the if condition but not emitting the `hreset`.

Comment: What are the values of `vals[1]` and `time` when you expect them to be the same?  Have you output those values in a `console.log()` to see what they actually are?  Obviously, they aren't `==` so you need to see what they actually are.

Comment: They are same for one hour.after every hour redis will be sending the next hour time stamp ..at that time it will check and send the emit command.everything is working fine upto that but the emit is not working some how

Comment: What is the value of the variable `client` in `client.emit(...)`?  Where did it come from?  You don't show that.  FYI, looking for exact time value matches is generally fraught with issues of close, but not exact match.  Usually you look for the first time some value exceeds a target value and trigger based on that - then reset the trigger value to the next milestone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use setInterval:

```
var obj = setInterval(yourFunc, 3600000); // 60*60*1000 ms

var yourFunc = function() {
    client.emit("message", data);
};
```

Comment: but this will call on every hour from the start of the application...i want it to be fired on every hour starting...

Comment: Then setInterval to 1000 (1s) and check before emitting if new Date().getMinutes == 00 and new Date().getSeconds == 00